# react-select clears my typed value when i lose focus or move on to next field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-class, react-select

So i'm new to react and working on a typeahead component using react-select library and asynchronously fetching suggested options based on the inputs typed in. Now let's say if i typed in "google" and now "google" might be included in the suggested options or not and if i move on to the next form field i lose my type value "google". Must i always click from the options? Could accept the typed in value without clicking from options. I attempted to do this with onBlur but it clears out the value.

Below is myCode:

```
// Form field using redux form
    <Field>
      name={FIELD_AUTO_COMPLETE}
      component={renderCompanyNameTypeAhead}
      text="text"
      placeHolder="Company Name"
    </Field>
```

And in my stateless function:

```
    const getOptions = () => async(input) => {
        let response = await fetchApi.getOptions(input);
        let dataRepsone = await response.json();
        const arr = dataResponse.data;
             if (arr) {
                return arr.map( obj => {
                   const newObj = {};
                   newObj.label = obj.name;
                   newObj.value = obj.id;
                   return newObj;
               });
             }
          };

   const renderCompanyNameTypeAhead = (props) => {
     const getOptions = loadOptions();
     return (
            <div>
              <AysncSelect
                 {...props}
                 value={(props.input.value) ? props.input.value : props.selectedValue}
                 type={props.type}
                 label={props.label}
                 onChange={(value) => props.input.onChange(value)}
                 onBlur={() => props.onBlur(pros.input.value)}
                 loadOption={getOptions}
                />
             </div>
    )}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @FrankerZ sorry about that was editing my code when i saw your comment

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an extra greater than symbol (>) here:

```
<AysncSelect>
```

change for:

```
<AysncSelect
```